Does there exist a Dehn filling of an irreducible 3-manifold with toroidal boundaries which is still irreducible?
Let $M$ be a compact, orientable, irreducible 3-manifold with incompressible toroidal boundary (there might be more than one boundary component). Is it always possible to choose appropriate slopes on each boundary component, so that the resulting Dehn filling produces an irreducible closed 3-manifold?

Corollary 1.2 of Gordon-Litherland's paper shows that for any toroidal boundary component, there are at most 6 Dehn fillings making the manifold reducible. Therefore, a generic filling of all boundary components is going to be irreducible.
As Sam pointed out, this improves an earlier result of Hatcher (which was already sufficient for the purpose of this question).

Your link is to a paper by Gordon and Litherland, not Gordon and Luecke.  Note also that the [GL] paper cites (an early version of) Hatcher's theorem on the first page.

Yes.  This follows from the characterisation of boundary slopes as a (union of) Lagrangian subspaces of the “symplectic space” of all slopes. See Theorem 1 of Hatcher’s paper.
